# Как правильно быстро передавать строку на экран айфона?

Tags: ios, objective-c, счетчики, камера

Пытаюсь реализовать счётчик. Суть в том, что некоторая строка должна передаваться на экран смартфона со скоростью кадров, то есть 20-30 раз в секунду.

Реализую эту прелесть с помощью передачи кадров. Как-то так:

**CODE UPDATE** (17:00; 01.07.2016 МСК)

```
//.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int N = 0; //Глобальная переменная для подсчета кадров 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label; //строка на экране

@end 



//.m file
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

{
    AVCaptureSession *session;

}
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self setupCaptureSession];

  }

    - (void)setupCaptureSession    //инициализация сессии съемки
    {

        NSError *error = nil;          
        session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];          

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice                                       
                                   defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];       


        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

        if (!input) {                
        }

        [session addInput:input];

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL); //создание очереди кадров            
        [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];// создание буфера сэмплов и добавление очереди 
         [session addOutput:output];
         [session startRunning];

    }

//В методе строкой ниже, осуществляется передача кадров с камеры в буфер
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput

didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer

       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection

{
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"N = %d", N]; //to create string with global variable N
    self.Label.text = text; //вывести строку на экран айфона
    NSLog(text); //распечатать строку в консоль
    N++;
}

@end
```

Передача получается, но ооочень медленная. Строка на экране обновляется не раньше, чем через 10 секунд после запуска приложения. И более того, иногда запускаю приложение, а строка вообще не хочет обновляться.

**Вопрос:** есть ли способ более эффективно передавать строку на экран смартфона? Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: проверьте, что это все дело происходит на main thread

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko а как проверить? Я почти нуб.

Comment: у `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` есть свойство `sampleBufferCallbackQueue` где вы можете указать поток на котором вызывать ваш метод. передайте туда main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20-30 раз в секунду обновить строчку для девайса это вообще не проблема. Но стоит проверить как часто вызывается метод captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:. Если он редко вызывается, то тут уже ничего не сделаешь. Добавь в этом методе вывод в лог.

UI попробуй обновлять так (чтоб точно было из главного потока):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update UI
            self.Label.text = text;
        });
```

Comment: Метод хорошо вызывается. Как раз 20 раз в секунду. `NSLog(@"sometext ");` - выскакивает тоже пропорционально методу. А вот обновление на экране смартфона медленнее. (Иногда запускаю - вообще не обновляется).

Comment: dispatch_async не помог? Тогда можешь попробовать dispatch_sync или обновление других компонентов (ячеек, кнопок) или других свойств (frame, alpha, image). Особенно внимательно с UIImageView попробуй

Comment: чуть-чуть не ясно. Я добавил код в вопрос. Может скажете более конкретно, куда я должен `dispatch_asynk` добавить?

Comment: dispatch_async нужно добавить в метод captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer: Грубо говоря, обновление интерфейса должно быть в блоке dispatch_async

Comment: спасибо. Всё заработало.

Comment: а где нибудь на русском про dyspatch_asynk можно прочитать, вы случайно не знаете? Или вы сие из Apple docs знаете?

Comment: На хабре почитать можно, Эпл дока тоже лишней не будет. Поищи немного